How to make All Threads Run Low/Idle CPU Priority?
I want to set all threads or .exe to Low CPU Priority in Task Manager so that their CPU-usage doesn't interfere with my game and make my gameplay microstutter and cause some input delay from keyboard. I for example listen to a youtube video or have something going on in the background while playing a game and want only my game to have high or realtime CPU priority usage.
How can I select all instances of google chrome.exe or steam.exe (with its around 10 instances of steamhelper.exe) or other threads and set them with one mouse click to low priority? After that I will set only my game to high or realtime cpu usage.
Only some of the subthreads are set to low priority when doing it in Process Explorer, I wonder why not all are set to low?

If you are worried about Chrome affecting the performance of your system, why don't you close Chrome? Chrome CPU usage should decrease significantly when it's minimized. Any event if you are playing video in the background that will use significant CPU resources because it's YouTube.

I mean there are not only Google Chrome .exe subthreads but also a lot of other .exe processes going on. They can cause microstutter or input delay when I need to be quick in my game. I can't close them all and some of them I want to keep active. It's not high amount CPU usage which is problem but sudden microstutter or input delay  and this can be avoided by decreasing priority level of those other .exe but I want to do them all with one click, not one by one.

Threads do have priority. However, they can set it themselves.

Be careful with setting realtime priority. It will completely hang your system if the process in question reaches 100% utilization, and will displace other things that actually require realtime priority.

It only stutters from Realtime CPU priority if it reaches 100%, otherwise it improves performance of the application. My CPU doesn't reach 100% usage so my game benefits  (by feeling, not exact test) from having Realtime CPU usage in regard to input delay and responsiveness. But it does that more reliably if the other active apps have low priority. I wrote to FeedbackHub in Windows 10 that I want with one click set all .exe to low/idle level.
